# How to optimize groupBy() operation on Spark RDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

My question is about alternatives/optimization to `groupBy()` operation on RDD. I have millions of `Message` instances which needs to be grouped based on some ID. I use `groupBy()` to accomplish the goal but I know the fact that it is  an expensive one and it takes huge amount of processing time .

So I tried `reduceByKey(func)` and `combineByKey()` as an alternative which was suggested in some of resources that I went through but its not a fit to my scenario where 
 ***My requirement is just grouping***. But my data size is huge where `groupBy` consumes more **than 70% of my job's time**.So any suggestions or solution are appreciated.

**My input Data**

> Seq(new Message("1", "abc", "Request"), new Message("1", "cba",
>   "Response"), new Message("2", "def", "Request"), new Message("2",
>   "fed", "Response"), new Message("3", "ghi", "Request"), new
>   Message("3", "ihg", "Response"))

For the sake of simplicity, i have given input data in `Seq`

```
 def groupMessages(sourceRdd: RDD[Message]): Unit {

    val messageIdRdd = sourceRdd.mapPartitions(partitionData => {
      partitionData.map(row => (row.uniqueID(), row))

    })

    /*
     Group messages based on its message id. This functionality is to combine request response
     together as single transaction based on message id.
     */
    val groupbyRdd = messageIdRdd.groupBy(_._1) 
}
```

**Expected Result**

> (2,CompactBuffer((2,Message(2,def,Request)),
>   (2,Message(2,fed,Response))))
>   (3,CompactBuffer((3,Message(3,ghi,Request)),
>   (3,Message(3,ihg,Response))))
>   (1,CompactBuffer((1,Message(1,abc,Request)),
>   (1,Message(1,cba,Response))))

Comment: what do you mean by `group rows` ? please illustrate with example data and expected output.

Comment: @mtoto thanks for your response. I updated my post. hope the given details are clear enough.

Comment: "My requirement is just grouping". Grouping is inherently an expensive operation on  a large data set. There may be no magic bullet here

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using groupByKey() rather than groupBy() to have execution happen in cluster.

```
val myRDD = sc.parallelize( List(("1", "abc", "Request"), ("1", "cba", "Response"), ("2", "def", "Request"), ("2", "fed", "Response"), ("3", "ghi", "Request"), ("3", "ihg", "Response")) )
```

Your groupBy() is:

```
scala> myRDD.map(x=>x).groupBy(_._1).take(10).foreach(println)
(2,CompactBuffer((2,def,Request), (2,fed,Response)))
(3,CompactBuffer((3,ghi,Request), (3,ihg,Response)))
(1,CompactBuffer((1,abc,Request), (1,cba,Response))))
```

groupByKey() code would be:

```
scala> myRDD.map(x=>(x._1,x)).groupByKey().take(10).foreach(println)
(2,CompactBuffer((2,def,Request), (2,fed,Response)))
(3,CompactBuffer((3,ghi,Request), (3,ihg,Response)))
(1,CompactBuffer((1,abc,Request), (1,cba,Response))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: is ter any performance difference between groupByKey() and  groupBy() ?

Comment: Yes for huge data. groupBy(): processing happens at driver/client program. groupByKey() happens at mappers (in cluster), remember this also is expensive but you said you have no choice but to use grouping, because this involves much shuffling (movement of data to the key location).

Comment: the point you made is not correct. I made detail analysis on this. 
https://balajireddyblog.blogspot.in/2016/12/groupby-vs-groupbykey-in-this-posti.html

Comment: Good analysis on your blog. As far as I think, it is implicit that Scala/Spark uses Hash-Partitioning for keys (in both cases here). The real advantage is imminent when you are running on huge data in cluster, it matters where it is happening.

Answer (score -1):

If your requirement is only grouping you can go for groupByKey(). If you are going to do aggregation(sum,avrage,etc) you can use either reduceByKey()or combinedByKey(). The main difference between  reduceByKey() and combinedByKey() is the return type. The reduceByKey() return type should match the value type but in combinedByKey() may be different. As you response is look like you are only interested in grouping you can go for groupByKey().

Comment: yes. My requirement is just grouping. But my data size is huge where groupBy consumes more than 70% of my job's time. so i'm looking for better solution.

Comment: Right now 20+. But numbers will be going up in near future.

Comment: number of partitions and cores plays major role here, If you have sufficient cores increase partition size and try

Comment: Sure will do that.

Comment: Design perspective groupByKey()  is right choice because other two functions are optimized for aggregation and as you are saying this task is taking 70% of your job, its aging depends what are all the other   transformation and actions you are using after this stage. The optimization we can use is making the all the partitions are evenly loaded(number and size).  If any of the partition is too large also make the job run long.

Comment: you are right. as i mentioned ,  this consumes about 70% of my time where as other transformations takes quit less.(status seen from spark UI)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128830/discussion-between-prudvi-sagar-and-balaji-reddy).